# Ag-Sn-Cu Phase diagram to formulate homogenization temperature / duration

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, metal, metallurgy, alloy

I am working on Ag-Sn-Cu alloy phase diagram to figure out the best temperature / duration to homogenize the alloy (annealing). The %age of elements in the alloy are

1. Ag - 40 %
2. Cu - 27.8 %
3. Sn - 32.2 %

(Composition can be varied if necessary but not more than 5 %)

Now the main goal is:

1. Find out the temperature / time duration at which the ingot of the above said alloy should be annealed to get the maximum Ag3Sn phase in the final ingot. Ag3Sn is the most desired phase with Cu3Sn being the second desired phase. Anyhow the main goal is to make as much Ag3Sn as possible.
2. The time duration for which the ingot should be placed at the desired temperature. (The total ingot is usually 6–7 kg)
3. [Supplementary question] Should the temperature be gradually reduced to the desired level of maximum Ag3Sn yield (or gradually increased)?

The phase diagram of Ag-Sn-Cu is as follows:
[image: Ag-Su-Cu Phase Diagram]

Comment: I'm away from my relevant databases now, but two comments: phase diagrams will not help with kinetic questions, and that particular phase diagram is not the best for your question. Early next week I'll have s real answer for you.

Comment: thanks @JonCuster .. Any tip to lead me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much of this answer is based on a document available from NIST at [Properties of Ternary Copper-Silver Systems](http://www.nist.gov/data/PDFfiles/jpcrd45.pdf) [originally J. Phys. Chem. Ref. Data, 6(3) 621-673 (1977)] - this has an equivalent to the diagram in the question (which is just the surface of the liquidus). Now, since you are talking about balances of solid phases, it is also worth looking at the binary diagrams to discuss those.

For Ag-Sn, one gets:
[image: Ag-Sn Binary diagram calculated from Kattner et al.]

For Cu-Sn there is:
[image: Cu-Sn Binary diagram calculated from Miettinen]

Now I'll throw out a few observations:
Ag$_{3}$Sn is a line compound, which in the binary system is not stable above 480C. In the NIST report this phase is referenced as $\theta$, but called Ag$_{3}$Sn($\epsilon$), causing great confusion since the $\zeta$ Ag-Sn phase is designated $\epsilon_{2}$, and Cu$_{3}$Sn($\epsilon$) is designated $\epsilon_{1}$. So, watch it...

The Cu$_{3}$Sn line compound converts to the fcc $\gamma$ phase at around 676C. The $\gamma$ phase is sometimes also referred to as Cu$_{3}$Sn (yet more confusion possible). The Cu$_{3}$Sn and Ag$_{3}$Sn line compounds are different crystal structures, and do not form a solid solution across the ternary.

For both Ag-Sn and Cu-Sn, another thing to notice is the various other phases that are in close proximity to the Ag$_{3}$Sn and Cu$_{3}$Sn line compounds. Going into the ternary system, you get questions like how adding Cu into $\zeta$Ag-Sn impacts the free energy.

So, what now? In the NIST report, on page 664 is a pseudo-binary diagram where the Sn wt% is held at 20%, and Cu wt% is varied from 0 to 80 (balance Ag). Personally I hate weight percent, but...  The point that one can eventually pick out is that the Ag$_{3}$Sn phase, designated $\theta$ appears almost nowhere - there is just a little sliver way over near 0 wt% Cu and under 250C. It appears that with the addition of Cu, the $\zeta$Ag-Sn phase rapidly replaces the Ag$_{3}$Sn phase.

So, as far as I can tell, I'm not sure that the kinetics even matter here. You basically can't get much Ag$_{3}$Sn to form within the ternary parameters you have chosen - you will get $\zeta$Ag-Sn instead.

Comment: Insightful. That explains a lot. I have been looking into other documentations and here is something which I found can be a little importance. This [paper](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Przemyslaw_Fima/publication/237073772_Thermal_analysis_of_selected_SnAgCu_alloys/links/02e7e51b39c2ce3451000000.pdf)  on page 735 explains the behaviour and existence of phases. Ag3Sn & Cu3Sn & liq would exist between 385 - 435.  Though the Ternary parameters are not exactly wo what I'd like but still .... What is your take?

Comment: And the main goal of the question is to maximize the Ag3Sn .. We can compromise on the Cu3Sn phase.

Comment: Interesting. There would appear to be some contradictions between your reference and mine.  The NIST ternary and pseudo-binaries are quite complicated compared to the Fima paper you cite. On the other hand, all of their data (on, say Figure 3) are in the simplest part of the ternary, away from ugliness of the low Sn content areas of the Ag-Sn and Cu-Sn diagrams.  But, take their Figure 3 as fact - where does that leave you? If you try to solidify at ~25 at.% Sn and Ag rich, you will first form a liquid+$\zeta$ mix, and then hope that you can convert the $\zeta$ to Ag$_{3}$Sn. Not easy.

Comment: Well, the original ingredients %wt would be 32.2 % Sn, with Ag 40% n Copper 27.8%  .. (not exactly Fig 3 but somehow close, *fingers crossed*).  My brainwave is to cool down the melt to around 400 C and keep it there, middle point to avoid the zeta & high enough to sustain acceptable Ag3Sn precipitation. Your thoughts ?

Comment: You can't avoid passing through the liquid-zeta region unless you splat cool (perhaps). So you will get some zeta forming. Then the liquid will get richer in Sn. Once you finally hit the top of the Ag$_{3}$Sn line you will start forming it and stuff to the Sn-rich side of the curve.  To convert whatever zeta you made will require Sn to diffuse back into the zeta and have the zeta nucleate and transform into zeta.  A tough problem.

Comment: Well the method tried right now quenching the ingot once its 700 - 800 to room temp and then heating it again. Another point, with some maths, the amount of Sn (33.2 %) is used up in creating Ag3Sn & Cu3Sn (if both are formed completely), so while we are creating Ag3Sn & Cu3Sn, Sn is depleting as well.

Comment: To simplify the solidification issue - assume pure Ag-Sn, starting with 25 at.% Sn, just perfect to end up with pure Ag$_{3}$Sn. You melt it all together and start cooling.  At around 950K you nucleate fcc Ag with ~12 at.% Sn in it. As you continue cooling, the liquid moves down the liquidus line to the right, and at 900K you have ~30 at.% Sn in the liquid, and the stable solid phase jumps from fcc Ag(Sn) to zeta Ag-Sn. You continue cooling down to ~760K where Ag$_{3}$Sn becomes the preferred stable solid phase, and the liquid has 45 at.%Sn in it.

Comment: So, you have made a good percentage of solid, but not the right phase, and if that won't transform quickly (and it won't) you have to wait for diffusion.  Your approach is about as good as it gets for an ingot, but it might take a long time to convert.

Comment: You are right, but this doesn't yield better results (tested) .. I have another approach in mind. What if we plot the precipitation kinetics? I came across a tool called pandat which can plot the precipitation of an alloy phases over time. But it requires kinetic databases for certain parameters. To build that we need the following parameters for Ag-Sn-Cu alloy.


Molar_Volume,  Interfacial_Energy, Atomic_Spacing, Nucleation_Site_Parameter, Driving_Force_Factor.

Comment: As per my discussion with their customer service, 
- Molar_Volume and Atomic_Spacing of a certain crystal structure. You do not need the exact values, but the right magnitude.
- Driving_Force_Factoris usually given as 1
- Nucleation_Site_Parameter, which is related to defect, is usually given a value in the order of 10^-4 to 10^-6
- Interfacial_Energy is usually not available, you will need some experimental data on the precipitates, such as evolution of particle size and volume fraction to optimize this kinetic parameter.

Comment: Do you know of any knowledge base which can help in getting these details for Ag-Cu-Sn ternary system?

Comment: From another question it looks like you have tried CompuTherm with no luck. The other big player is ThermoCalc (thermocalc.com). I don't believe it comes cheap, but you could at least check with them if their software could do the job (or if they would consult on it).

Comment: Interestingly, CompuTherm Pandat demo allows you to analyze alloys with upto 3 elemental compositions ...

Comment: Thanks for recommending Thermo-Calc btw, great tool. I was looking at property diagrams for the alloy composition above & [this](http://s22.postimg.org/dxsazbvs1/image.png) is what I get for different temperatures. Up till 435 Ag3Sn phase is produced.

Comment: One more thing, The actual phase composition for AG3SN_L60_CU3TI is (Ag,Cu)0.75(Ag,Sn)0.25 & CU3SNSB_GAMMA_IM is (Cu)0.75 (Cu,Sn)0.25 .. How do we find out how much Ag3Sn total exist in all of this system?